# OTP-Firebase sms works good on IOS which recognize to google by app attest on App Check and SHA265, on android works very good just on debug mode

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-play, google-play-console

After many efforts i couldn't find a solution.

*The problem is in details:*

I am using google OTP- Firebase Phone number Authentication service to my app at the first Page, my environment is expo 48SDKs react-native which contain two parts which are IOS and Android app, using emulators for each one,  OTP Firebase works fine on both - IOS and Android emulators and in debug modes

After finish developing the app and being ready to be published:

**Phase One:**

First i begin to publish it on Apple App-store by Xcode and everything going fine but when app shows up on App store and download it - Suddenly OTP Phone auth not working.

So far founds solutions to IOS app by using few things ( credentials on iOS domain firebase project & google-service.plist which included it on Xcode  & app-Attest on App-Check on Google Firebase Project Overview) and rebuild and publish again new version, finally everything work's very good and smooth.

**Phase Two:**

Begin to publish the app on Google Play-store and makes these steps ( credentials -  SHA-1 & 265 included it on Android domain on firebase project Overview & google-service.JSON which included it on Android Studio in app folder &  Play integrity on App-Check on Google Firebase Project and Integrity API Enabled ), and app shows up on google play store - Suddenly sms auth firebase not working.

**Note**:  before integrity API using the SaftyNet API - app works fine but google services stop this API this month.

**Important** to know: the code works fine cuz it work on IOS app very good and on android debug mode and emulators

On Android app which downloaded it from google-play ( release mode ) still not working and i don't know what to do, makes a lot of searching and try to modifying the code but nothing.

takes a lot of tutorials and rebuilds succeeded and did add new implementations on Build.Gradle & tries very much things still nothing.

**Note i am working with**:

React-native ~18 and expo 48 sdks.

New Mac System , buy before two month.

the last Android Studio version.

the last Xcode version.

Help please and thank you.